# Allocating void pointer inside function C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

If i allocate a void pointer like this, then i get an access violation while trying to free the pointer.

```
int Foo(void* ptr)
{
     *((void**)ptr) = malloc(25);
     ((char*)ptr)[0] = 'A';
     free(ptr); //crashes access violation
}
```

The same happens if i pass a void pointer to the function and tries to free it outside of the function

```
int main()
{
     void* ptr;
     Foo(&ptr);
     printf("%s \n", (char*)&ptr); //works
     free(ptr); //crashes access violation
     retun 0;
}
```

any clues how to free this pointer?

Comment: I'm pretty deleting void pointers produces is undefined. Does it really need to be void?

Comment: Freeing a void pointer is perfectly fine. In fact, `free` is prototyped as `void free(void *ptr)` -- it **has** to be.

Comment: You can't even compile this code. How can it crash?

Comment: `*((char*)ptr)[0] = 'A';` doesn't even compile.

Comment: Are you forced to use `void*`? I'd always prefer using known types, if you just want a buffer of bytes, use unsigned char. And your cast on line 3 looks very suspicious..

Comment: This code is... I don't even have words...

Comment: @NikBougalis I know this code is probably the worst you've seen, this isn't the code i am using, just a small part of it, but it describes my problem with the pointer allocation and freeing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not trying to free the same pointer, try `free(*((void**)ptr));`

Comment: this also produces an access violation

Comment: however seemse like this would be the way to go, was a totally different error.

Answer (score 2):

That is wrong, you can't free ptr in your function, to avoid confusion pass `void**`:

```
int Foo(void** ptr)
{
   *ptr = malloc(25);
   ((char *)*ptr)[0] = 'A';
   free(*ptr); 
}
```

Comment: Dereferencing a void pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't think the code would even compile if you tried to take the contents of a void pointer. Apart from that, this is a good answer.

Comment: Thanks Lundin, code edited to fix compilation issue